# Rulings that Sephardim should stand to put on hand-t'filin

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, standing-sitting

[Rabbi Shimon Eider](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Eider)'s book, *Student Edition of Halachos of Tefillin*, dates to 1985. In it (section Ⅲ D 7), he writes:

> Some [Poskim](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1428) hold that one should sit while putting on [the Shel Yad](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin) and stand while putting on [the Shel Rosh](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin); this is the [minhag](/tags/minhag/info) of [Sefardim](/tags/sephardi-mizrachi-eastern/info). Other Poskim hold that one should stand while putting on both the Shel Yad and Shel Rosh; this is the minhag of [Ashkenazim](/tags/ashkenazi/info).

The claim that Sephardic Jews customarily sit, and Ashkenazic Jews customarily stand, while donning the hand-*t'filin* accords also with what I have always understood to be the case (for what it's worth). There's [a little more information on this practice](/q/33756) elsewhere on Mi Yodeya.

However, in the past year or so, I have seen three or four Sephardic Jews in Ashkenazic synagogues donning the hand-*t'filin* while standing. While it's possible that they have decided to follow the custom of the community in which they're participating (an idea with [halachic](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/597) basis in some contexts), I wonder whether there is more to it than that. Specifically:

**Has any Sephardic rabbi ruled, *specifically citing* the custom of sitting to don hand-*t'filin*, that Sephardic Jews should ignore that practice and stand (either generally, or in an Ashkenazic synagogue)? What are the details of this ruling and who issued it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sephardic communities that stand to put on hand-t'filin](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67270/sephardic-communities-that-stand-to-put-on-hand-tfilin)

Comment: @sabbahillel, how is this a duplicate at all? They're asking completely different questions.

Comment: Maybe there's a concern of "lo sisgodedu," and that these Sephardim you saw putting on tefillin while standing were doing so because of this?