# Sephardic communities that stand to put on hand-t'filin

Tags: minhag, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, standing-sitting, communities

[Rabbi Shimon Eider](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Eider)'s book, *Student Edition of Halachos of Tefillin*, dates to 1985. In it (section Ⅲ D 7), he writes:

> Some [Poskim](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1428) hold that one should sit while putting on [the Shel Yad](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin) and stand while putting on [the Shel Rosh](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin); this is the [minhag](/tags/minhag/info) of [Sefardim](/tags/sephardi-mizrachi-eastern/info). Other Poskim hold that one should stand while putting on both the Shel Yad and Shel Rosh; this is the minhag of [Ashkenazim](/tags/ashkenazi/info).

The claim that Sephardic Jews customarily sit, and Ashkenazic Jews customarily stand, while donning the hand-*t'filin* accords also with what I have always understood to be the case (for what it's worth). There's [a little more information on this practice](/q/33756) elsewhere on Mi Yodeya.

However, in the past year or so, I have seen three or four Sephardic Jews in Ashkenazic synagogues donning the hand-*t'filin* while standing. While it's certainly possible that they are ignorant of the common practice or have decided on their own to ignore it in an Ashkenazic synagogue in order to act like those around them (an idea with [halachic](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/597) basis in some contexts), I wonder whether there is more to it than that. Specifically:

**Are there any Sephardic communities that have always had the custom of standing to don hand-*t'filin*? Which?**

Comment: The original custom may have been to stand while saying the b'racha as the source for sitting comes from the zohar, which is a relatively recent book. So if the custom comes from the Zohar, you might have certain old communities who stand, and certain communities who sit, without knowing it comes from the zohar. i believe the shulchan arukh rules that you should stand

Comment: @Aaron, I don't think the _SA_ rules either way. Also, the age of the _Zohar_ is a matter of much discussion (as I'm sure you know), but even assuming arguendo that it's no older than when it was found, it could still be referring to an older practice.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I do not have the time to check each source specifically, but here are a few pointers:

Rabbi Shalom Jerby from Nofit in Israel [says](http://www.nofitmoreshet.org/BRPortal/br/P102.jsp?arc=43228) that Sephardic communities in many places stand, including Tunisia, Morocco, Algeria, and more.

Rabbi Ovadia Yosef [says](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_3.html) that even though *lechatchila* one should stand, there's a *sod* to sitting, and he brings a few sources there as well.

Good luck!

Comment: With a name like ["Jerby"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djerba#History_of_Djerba.27s_Jewish_community) he sounds like he would know the customs of Tunisia. Many thanks for your citation to his explanation; +1. But I don't see the relevance of your citation to Rabbi Yosef: the question was about communities with a tradition of standing, and he doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: Yes @msh210 you are right, sorry, I just stumbled upon that one, and thought to include it as it specifically mentions that according to *kabbalah* Rabbi Yosef says that they sit, so that might be the reason for some of the mentioned communities.